# Find the limit of a convergent sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let $a_n$ be the solution of the equation $ x^n+x-1=0$

Please help me find the limit of $(a_n)$

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Do you mean the real solution? What have you tried?

Comment: Hint: the positive real solution of $x^n-2x^{n-1}+1=0$ approaches $2$.

Comment: For now i have proven that a_n is increasing and a_n<1 for all n so the limit exist and i want to find the real solution

Comment: @KamalSaleh i have not yet know the path can you clarify a bit

Comment: Oh sorry that doesn't help, I think you can use Vieta's formulas: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas I think It will help you in finding the roots.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Imagining the graph below for large values of n with x values between -1 and 1
$$f(x)=x^n+x-1$$
$$-1<x<1=>x^n=0$$

Comment: Is the answer is 1

Comment: And how i can prove it

Comment: This question goes against our [quality standard policy](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508). Instead of posting an answer, you should encourage the person who posted the question to improve it.